# vtkRenderWindow does not open a graphics window

Tags: python, vtk

The vtkRenderWindow does not open a window after compiling my python code.

I have found a basic vtk example to troubleshoot the problem but I can't seem to find any solutions.

The code runs without any errors but no window well open to show the image.

I had the same problem with matplotlib and had to change the backend to TkAgg to show any graphics.

Thanks for your help!

```py
import vtk
from vtk.util.colors import tomato

cylinder = vtk.vtkCylinderSource()
cylinder.SetResolution(8)

cylinderMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
cylinderMapper.SetInputConnection(cylinder.GetOutputPort())

cylinderActor = vtk.vtkActor()
cylinderActor.SetMapper(cylinderMapper)
cylinderActor.GetProperty().SetColor(tomato)
cylinderActor.RotateX(30.0)
cylinderActor.RotateY(-45.0)

ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren)
iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

ren.AddActor(cylinderActor)
ren.SetBackground(0.1, 0.2, 0.4)
renWin.SetSize(200, 200)


iren.Initialize()

ren.ResetCamera()
ren.GetActiveCamera().Zoom(1.5)
renWin.Render()
iren.Start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying your vtkRenderer object after you have added it to your vtkRenderWindow object. Plus you modify your vtkRenderWindow object after you set it to your interactor object. I would suggest to keep things ordered (follow one after another) - **not tested**, requires Mesa 10.6.5 or later and OpenGL 3.2. or later:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import vtk
from vtk.util.colors import tomato

if __name__ == '__main__':

  cylinder = vtk.vtkCylinderSource()
  cylinder.SetResolution(8)

  cylinderMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
  cylinderMapper.SetInputConnection(cylinder.GetOutputPort())

  cylinderActor = vtk.vtkActor()
  cylinderActor.SetMapper(cylinderMapper)
  cylinderActor.GetProperty().SetColor(tomato)
  cylinderActor.RotateX(30.0)
  cylinderActor.RotateY(-45.0)

  ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
  ren.AddActor(cylinderActor)
  ren.SetBackground(0.1, 0.2, 0.4)
  ren.ResetCameraClippingRange()  #instead of ren.ResetCamera()
  #ren.GetActiveCamera().Zoom(1.5) #keep this out for a while (suspicious, because you request a zoom without doing something with it)

  renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
  renWin.AddRenderer(ren)
  renWin.SetWindowName("some title") #just a bonus
  renWin.SetSize(200, 200)

  #style = vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera() #later uncomment this for test
  iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
  iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)
  #iren.SetInteractorStyle(style) #later uncomment this for test
  iren.Initialize()

  renWin.Render()
  iren.Start()
```